# What is the correct term for all the forms and derivatives of a root word?

Tags: terminology, derivational-morphology, derivation

I want to make a comprehensive word list, and I want to refer to that list using the accurate terminology.

In my list I want all the forms, extensions, derivatives, etc of each word. I am using the word "forms" but is that right?

For instance "glass" is a root word.... Some forms are "glassed", "glasses", "glassy", "glassiest", "glassier", "glassing", "glazing", and probably more... And "blue" is a root word and some forms are "blueness", "bluish", "blued", "bluing", "blues", "bluesy" and more, but not necessarily "bluegrass" or all the other words containing that sequence of four letters. (Those may be distinct root words, with their own derivative forms).

Is there a term for all the derivations of a root?

I am having a hard time even *searching* the web for what I want because I don't know the **word**! Is it "derivations", "derivatives", "morphs", or something?

P.S. it is for a software project involving random words in a security system.

Comment: Well, the big question is how close do you want the relation to be? _Glass_ is a noun and _glaze_ is a verb, _glassy_ is an adjective, _glasses_ is a noun, _glass-eyed_ is an adjective, _glass chin_ is a noun compound, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A term for the collective is

> **word family**
>
> A group of cognate words especially within a single language
>
> The *word family* to which English *write, rewrite, writer*, and *writ* belong [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/word%20family)

> **word family**  n.  [compare German *Wörterfamilie* (1765)]
>
> **1869**   T.
> Turner *6th Eng. Reading Bk.* ii. 130   We..see that, from a parent
> stem-word, we obtain a large **word-family.**
>
> **1926**   H. W. Fowler *Dict. Mod. Eng. Usage* 553/2   A phonetically consistent method is in English peculiarly hard to reconcile with the keeping together of **word families.**
>
> **2000**   *Today's Parent* Oct. 61/1   Hearing that initial letter..is the big early reading skill. From that, kids can use all the rimes to make **word families**. (OED)

> A **word family** is a group of words with a common base to which
> different prefixes and suffixes are added. For example, members of the
> word family based on the headword, base, stem, or root word work
> include *rework, worker, working, workshop*, and *workmanship*, among
> others. Similar words are called **paronyms**. [Richard Nordquist; "Word
> Family: Definition and Examples in English"](https://www.thoughtco.com/word-family-1692609)

> **paronym** (n.)
>
> A word which is derived from another word, or from a word with the
> same root, and having a related or similar meaning (e.g. *childhood* and
> *childish*); a derivative or cognate word. OED

Comment: "Paronym" is probably the right term. I could call such a list "A list of words that can be sorted by paronyms" But yours and several answers here have raised a hundred new questions. I'm following the threads. "Word family" is probably not the best term as it often means semantically distant words with related spelling such as "jug" and "rug".

Comment: *Jug* and *rug* would be *three-letter words* or *rhymes*, but  "word family" to me means words with your relationship, i.e., I knew the term before looking for  definitions. *Paronym* isn't well known and IMO  describes the relationship between words better than a complete set of such words.

Answer (score 0):

A term that fits your description is "*word form*". It is found in the following articles from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphology_(linguistics)).

> [Lexemes and word forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphology_(linguistics)#Lexemes_and_word_forms)
> The term "word" has no well-defined meaning. Instead, two related terms are used in morphology: lexeme and word-form. Generally, a lexeme is a set of inflected word-forms that is often represented with the citation form in small capitals. For instance, the lexeme eat contains the word-forms eat, eats, eaten, and ate. Eat and eats are thus considered different word-forms belonging to the same lexeme eat. Eat and Eater, on the other hand, are different lexemes, as they refer to two different concepts.

> [**Lexeme-based morphology**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphology_(linguistics)#Lexemes_and_word_forms)
>
> Lexeme-based morphology usually takes what is called an item-and-process approach. Instead of analyzing a word form as a set of morphemes arranged in sequence, a word form is said to be the result of applying rules that alter a word-form or stem in order to produce a new one. An inflectional rule takes a stem, changes it as is required by the rule, and outputs a word form; a derivational rule takes a stem, changes it as per its own requirements, and outputs a derived stem; a compounding rule takes word forms, and similarly outputs a compound stem.

It can be seen from this description that, all three processes, inflection, derivation, and word compounding are covered.

Comment: Maybe. From all these good answers, more questions arise! It may get messy. I think the term "paronym" as in @DjinTonic's answer is close, but I may have to use more than one term to capture all of what I intend, including "word-forms" as you say. Like "A list of words each with all word-forms, sortable by paronym..."

Answer (score -1):

Maybe not strictly the best answer to your question, but might be close enough for your use:
“[Focal meaning](https://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/oi/authority.20110803095825884)” (Oxford Reference)